# How do I use subtraction and addition intermittently on a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have to add and subtract every other element in a vector like so:

1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5 ...

can I do this within a vector? if so how? if not what is a very basic way I can accomplish this?

Thanks, I'm new to R :)

Honestly I am completely stumped by this.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
2 * x[1] + sum(x*(-1)^seq_along(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** First note that the first two elements are both positive but after that they are alternating so treat 1 separately, extract the even and odd position elements after the first and sum each and then subtract the two sums adding x[1].  Note that this requires that x have length 3 or more.

```
x <- 1:5

x[1] + sum(x[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)]) - sum(x[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)])
## [1] -1

# check
1+2-3+4-5
## [1] -1
```

**2)** This can also be written as

```
sum(x[1], x[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)], - x[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)])
## [1] -1
```

**3)** This solution works even if the length of x is 0, 1 or 2 as well.  We create the vector c(1, 1, -1, 1, -1, ...) and multiply it by x and sum.

```
sum(replace(rep(c(-1, 1), length = length(x)), 1, 1) * x)
## [1] -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way. It will recycle the vector `c(1, -1)` to the length of `x`. If the length of `x` is not even, it gives  warning that must be suppressed since that is epected.

```r
x <- 1:5
sum(c(1, -1) * x) |> suppressWarnings()
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

[ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12158757/thomasiscoding) found a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974057/how-do-i-use-subtraction-and-addition-intermittently-on-a-vector/77974195?noredirect=1#comment137464939_77974195) in the above code. Here is his correction.

```r
x <- 1:5
(x[1] + sum(c(1,-1)*x[-1])) |> suppressWarnings()
#> [1] -1
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think it should be `-1`, since the first minus `-` happens to number `3`.

Comment: maybe you could use `x[1] + sum(c(1,-1),x[-1])` to fix it

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding You are right, I will edit.